# How to capture blocks of repetating text using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to select blocks of text within given string. These blocks of text have almost similar pattern.
For example, in text given below I want to capture line starting with "client" i.e. I want to select information of 3 clients given in text below.
Sometimes this information may not start with word "client", it may start with word "customer" or "project title" or "employer" words.

```
1. Client Name
          The XXX Company
Title
          Application Dev Office 
Period
          September 2008 Till date 
Role
          Quality Analyst Lead
Responsibilities
         Testing

Client Name
          The XYZ Company
Title
          Application web
Period
          September 2009 Till date 
Role
          Quality Tester Lead
Responsibilities
         Testing and destroying


3) Client Name
          The 1234 Company
Title
          Application web RIA
Period
          September 2209 Till date 
Role
          Quality Lead
Responsibilities
         Developer
```

I have created one regular expression for this and it is as follows :

```
(\n|\r|\a|\f)(\s|\d|\.)*?
(?<id>(Client|Customer|Role|Organi(s|z)ation|Vendor|Company|Employer))
(\s|\S)*?(?=(\n|\r|\a|\f)(\s|\d|\.)*?(\k'id'))*?
```

I have used `(\n|\r|\a|\f)` because when I load text from file into string variable, ^ is not able to identify these characters.

Problem with this regular expression is that, it is able to identify  information of first two clients, but its not able to identify last client's information.

Anyone knows how to develope regular expression for this?
I am using C# for this.

Thanks in advance.

------------------ EDITED PART -------------------

I need to develop regex like, if client related information starts with word "client", then look if there r words like "role","enviornment", "vendor" are present.If such words are present, then only we can say that it is client related information.
But in some cases this information can start with other words like "employer". In this case we still have to search for words like "role","enviornment", "vendor".
That is the reason I created my regex like

```
(?<id>(Client|Customer|Role|Organi(s|z)ation|Vendor|Company|Employer))
```

If word "client" matches, then any of the words except "client" should match in subsequent text.
If any of the words is found, then again start looking for "client".

Comment: After the edit, I have no idea what it is you're trying to do. In your edited part, you're all of a sudden say that every client should have a "role", "environment" and "vendor", yet "environment" is mentioned nowhere in your text. Neither are examples given of anything but "Client" records. To get a meaningful reply, the least you should do is give examples of all the type of records you're trying to match and clearly indicate what parts you're trying to extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Regex may be falling over due to the ")" on item 3. Add a ) to the regex and it seems to go on fine:

```
(\n|\r|\a|\f)(\s|\d|\.|\))*?(?<id>(Client|Customer|Role|Organi(s|z)ation|Vendor|Company|Employer))(\s|\S)*?(?=(\n|\r|\a|\f)(\s|\d|\.)*?(\k'id'))*?
```

Comment: I checked my old regex and modified it as u suggested, but still I am not getting desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This will grab each client block, if that's what you want:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex("^[^A-Za-z]*Client(?:(?!^[^A-Za-z]*Client).)*", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```